# Nodejs errors on String.startsWith

Tags: node.js, twitch

I'm attempting to update my chatbot with the latest version of tmi.js, but I keep getting an error from "message.startsWith is not a function"

```
C:\Users\kel\Documents\channelyzer\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\commands.js:332
    if ((message.startsWith(".") && !message.startsWith("..")) || message.startsWith("/")  || message.startsWith("\\")) {
                 ^

TypeError: message.startsWith is not a function
at client.say (C:\Users\kel\Documents\channelyzer\node_modules\tmi.js\lib\commands.js:332:22)
at Object.chatUpdate (C:\Users\kel\Documents\channelyzer\js\twitch.js:50:17)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\kel\Documents\channelyzer\server.js:51:9)
at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

Output from node -v:

```
v8.9.0
```

I updated both tmi and node this morning and that is when this error began. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you checked to see that `message` is still what you think it is (a string)?

Comment: [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268600/startswith-in-node-js-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @Mark_M this was the issue. The updated tmi.js is now passing an object instead of the string I thought it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method, [but it's not yet supported in all browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-String.prototype_methods_String.prototype.startsWith). You can implement yours in node or client-side JS using any of the methods below

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, 0) !== -1;
};
```

or

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.substring(0, suffix.length) === suffix
};
```